# Relations and a graph

Tags: relations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUbNf.jpg)

1. Find at least one binary relation R on the set M of vertices of some subgraph 
   of the graph ​ such that the ordered pair (c, d) belongs to this subgraph. 
   (Define the relation R by defining it for all individual pairs of elements.)
2. How many total (linear) orders defined on the set of vertices of some 
   subgraph of the graph ​ can be found? Consider all subgraphs.
3. Is it possible to find a subgraph of the given graph ​, such that this 
   subgraph is a graphic representation of an equivalence relation on the set of 
   its vertices? Give reasoning.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem, and you should do your own homework. Please tell us what you have done to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is a subgraph a proper subgraph? In the usual definition, a graph $G$ is a subgraph of $G$.

---

1. Consider the subgraph with vertices $\{c, d\}$.
2. Consider

   - which of the single vertex subgraphs define a total order;
   - which of the double vertex subgraphs define a total order;
   - which of the triple  vertex subgraphs define a total order (add each external vertex to each of the above);
   - ...
3. Consider the loop $(a, a)$.